# Image size enlarging when drawing it on the Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a 46*46 png image . While I use the following code to draw it on the Canvas,the image is getting enlarged.

```
window.onload = function() 
{
    drawEx1();
}

var image1 = null;

function drawEx1() 
{
    image1 = new Image();
    image1.src =
    "unnamed.png";
    image1.addEventListener('load', drawImage1);
}

function drawImage1() 
{
    if (image1.height > 46) 
    {
        image1.height = 46;
    }
    context.drawImage(image1, 10, 10,image1.height,image1.height);
}
```

I have styled the `CANVAS` using a `CSS` for appearing it on the center of the browser.
What is it I'm doing wrong here. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use CSS to resize the canvas because it will distort the canvas content--stretching it. Instead resize the canvas element itself: `<canvas width=100 height=100>` or `document.getElementById('mycanvas').width=100;`

Comment: @markE that's actually a valid and super useful Answer, not a Comment. OP definitely uses width/height in *StyleSheet* to control the canvas size.

Comment: Thats the answer! +1 . Put it as the answer and I will accept it. Thanks. @markE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use CSS to resize the canvas because it will distort the canvas content--stretching it.

Instead resize the canvas element itself:

```
<canvas width=100 height=100> or 

document.getElementById('mycanvas').width=100;
```

Good luck with your project!